# How to clear uninitialized memory in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, initialization

I have an incoming unitialized string. I want to remove all the uninitialized memory characters after "Keep" (Keep췍췍췍췍췍췍). Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
WCHAR* sNew = new WCHAR[10];
sNew[0] = 'K';
sNew[1] = 'e';
sNew[2] = 'e';
sNew[3] = 'p';

_getch();
}
```

How do I achieve this? In this example, I know the length I want to keep is the first four elements of the array, BUT, I need to code it for varying lengths.

I read that the '췍' symbol is the default for Visual Studio in Debug mode, so in release mode it could be

Comment: What does "incomint string" mean? If it is some user input, how is it uninitialized? BTW: There is no `new` operator in C. You are using C++.

Comment: [`memset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)??

Comment: Normally you don't need to fill everything with 0. But you must terminate your string with a 0 byte after the last valid character.

Comment: You "remove uninitialized memory" by initializing it. Just give it a value. Remember that zero-terminated strings have to end in a zero. `'\0'`

Comment: What does _"remove"_ mean to you? Do you know how to use a `std::vector` or `std::string`?

Comment: If you are receiving a string in the form you are showing, then the problem here is not fixing it afterwards, but to fix the method you use to receive that string, which you are unfortunately not showing.

Comment: the string needs to be null-terminated. whatever is printing the string doesn't know where the string ends. add the null-terminator and the string will output cleanly.

Comment: I think its a design issue. C types, such as char and int, don't have constructors to make sure they are initialized. I think the appropriate solution is to replace WCHAR with wstring.

Answer (score 1):

You can zero out the entire memory with memset:

```
WCHAR* sNew = new WCHAR[10];
memset(sNew, 0, 10*sizeof(WCHAR));
```

If you're using this memory as a c-string, then you really just need to terminate the string with a null character.

```
WCHAR* sNew = new WCHAR[10];
sNew[0] = 'K';
sNew[1] = 'e';
sNew[2] = 'e';
sNew[3] = 'p';
sNew[4] = '\0';
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I tell when the uninitialized memory starts and my incoming string ends? I've simplified it here sy hard-coding "Keep".

Comment: I'd prefer `WCHAR* sNew = new WCHAR[10]{};` over `memset` to zero out the memory. @JeffR You can't _know_ where the uninitialized memory starts. You'll have to _know_

Comment: @JeffR It is not possible to distinguish between initialized and uninitialized objects, since trying to inspect the uninitialized object would be Undefined Behavior. You need to know or keep track of where the initialized values end yourself.

Comment: Ok, so it seems I will need to pass the *size* of the incoming string itself, not including all the uninitialized memory. @FrançoisAndrieux "It is not possible to distinguish between initialized and uninitialized objects, since trying to inspect the uninitialized object would be Undefined Behavior."

Answer (score 1):

##### Method 1

You can use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) as shown below:

```
WCHAR* sNew = new WCHAR[10];
std::fill(sNew, sNew + 10, 'a'); //i have used `a` as an example you can chose some other character according to your needs/preference
```

Or if you want to set characters after `Keep` in your example you could do:

```
WCHAR* sNew = new WCHAR[10];
sNew[0] = 'K';
sNew[1] = 'e';
sNew[2] = 'e';
sNew[3] = 'p';

std::fill(sNew + 4, sNew + 10, 'a'); //note the + 4 used here
```

##### Method 2

Also do note that you can **value initialize** all the elements of the array as shown below:

```
WCHAR* sNew = new WCHAR[10](); //note the empty pair of parenthesis
```

Answer (score 1):

Practically, I'd suggest a few things

- don't use C-style arrays like this and prefer the `string` type, letting the compiler optimize it (const for fixed strings)

  ```c
  std::string const foo = "bar";
  ```
- generally don't manufacture uninitialized memory where possible (for example, consider a vector which will manage the allocation state for you)

Comment: The problem is calling Windows APIs with std::string doesn't always work.

Comment: Microsoft only begets more Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize all members of the array like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    WCHAR* sNew = new WCHAR[10]{0};  // Set all members to zero.

    WCHAR  aNew[10]{0};              // Set all members to zero.

}
```